# Keep EditText focus when tapping on buttons

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-togglebutton

I have an EditText with three toggle buttons beneath it.

I want to keep the focus on the EditText AND have the keyboard stay visible when I tap on any of the three toggles. i.e. I do not want the keyboard to hide when the focus is outside the EditText (I should not see the keyboard hide then reopen).

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
toggleButton.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
        {
            editText.requestFocus(); 
            // This doesn't fully work. 
            // Focus is on editText but keyboard still hides when I 
            // tap on the toggle button.
        }
    });
```

The EditText and ToggleButtons are in a fragment, and the parent activity has this configuration in the AndroidManifest.

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/m_activity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
```

What is the best way to fix this issue?

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do that for your `yourEditText`, using `OnFocusChangeListener`

```
yourEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
        {
            yourEditText.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    });
```

This means that, you will request focus whenever it is changed for you `yourEditText` and you will also show keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LayoutParms.Example is given below

1.Hide the keyboard

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode
(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

2.Show the Keyboard

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode
(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

If you want to Know the other options. Refer the below link.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.
html